# POST error 500: Internal server error

Tags: forms, symfony, post

I'm trying to build a form with Symfony2 and when I click on my button to submit the form, i get a `POST` method with a 500 Internal server error.

Here is the code on my controller to validate the form:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid())
        {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();             
            $em->persist($group);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));
        }
    }
```

In the view:

```
    <form action="{{ path('new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
<div class="actions">
          <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
        </div>
```

But I receive nothing from the form. Someone can help me please ? This really weird bug.

Comment: Where is `$group` originally defined? 

Also, what is that actual error? Did you check your server logs?

Comment: $group is my entities, I can give more information: `Warning: array_replace_recursive(): Argument #1 is not an array in /home/public_html/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 583
`

Comment: Are you submitting any data from your form? If not, try that. If that doesn't work, can you do a `var_dump` or some other kind of test on `$request->request->get($form->getName())` and let us know what's there? It's choking on the `bindRequest` method.

Comment: I don't think this is whats causing your issue, but your form as it stands wont ever validate properly. You need to output the hidden fields, especially the CSRF token.

Comment: var_dump($request->request->get($form->getName())); Display NULL value.

Comment: I agree with MrGrlass. Try to add this to your view, inside the form tag: {{ form_rest(form) }}

Comment: Nothing better with {{ form_rest(form) }}

Comment: This error comes from my binRequest(), but I don't know wy it fail ...

Comment: Here is the error line: Warning: array_replace_recursive Argument #1 is not an array in Form.php line 583 (500 Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same issue with the form handling.

The solution is to clear the cache **manually** and warm up it again.

> php app/console cache:clear ==> Does'nt work for me, so I do:
>   rm -rf app/cache/dev
>   php app/console cache:warmup

That fix the problem!

But what was the issue?
I figure out that 500 Internal Server Error get's thrown becaus it try's to load the cached routing values in app/cache/dev/annotations (in my case)

Hint: I have used annotation for templating and routing before in the controller. Than I've chang this and now I'm using external file routing... And that was my pain... I've forgotten to clear the cache **manually**!!!