# Symfony Request - get Internal Server Error

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, request

I try to make an Ajax Post Request to a controller in my Project. I made a `var_dump()` of the $request and it shows me the full Request object including my sent data. If I try to access the data or make `var_dump($request->request);` (For the POST-Data) I get a Internal Server Error 500. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

View:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",        
    url: "/symfony/web/app_dev.php/setliste/{{entity.id}}/update",
    data: { dataArray : dataArray },
    error: function(x, status, error) {
        alert(status+error);
        console.log(x);
    }
}).done(function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Controller:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $test = $request;
    var_dump($test);
}
```

Alex

Comment: Well check if this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591340/post-error-500-internal-server-error

Comment: if you want an answer, you have to post some code ( controller , routing ) . check log files of symfony2  and webserver ,you may get some more idea.

Comment: yes more code please. Have you tried looking in the browser console what the XHR request return as response ?

Comment: thank you, I found that the controller must have a response (NULL given) :)

Comment: So, have you resolved the problem?

Comment: $request = $this->getRequest()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller action must have a `return` statement which contains a `Response`.

To solve this problem, change your code to :

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $test = $request;

    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(var_dump($test));
}
```